# How to stop 'is typing' function when user sends message

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, socket.io

My 'user is typing' function does not remove the 'is typing', when the user hits enter. So even though a user sends the message, the 'is typing' still displays, until the timer runs out.

Any ideas?

This is my code:

client-side

```
// Detect typing

      function timeoutFunction() {  
        typing = false;
        socket.emit("typing", false);
        socket.emit("notTyping", true)
      }

      $("#msg").keypress(function(e){
        if (e.which !== 13) {
          if (typing === false && $("#msg").is(":focus")) {
          typing = true;
          socket.emit("typing", true);
          } else {
              clearTimeout(timeout);
              timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 1500);
            }
        }
        else if(e.which == 13 && $("#msg").val() !== "") {
          $("#"+data.person+"").remove();
        }
      });

      socket.on("isTyping", function(data) {  
        if (data.isTyping) {
          if ($("#"+data.person+"").length === 0) {
            socket.emit("checkTypingFunction");
            $("#chat").append("<div id='"+ data.person +"'><span class='grey'>" + data.person + " is typing...</div>");
            timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 1500);
          }
        } else {
           $("#"+data.person+"").remove();
          }
      });
```

server-side:

```
client.on("typing", function(data) {  
    if (typeof people[client.id] !== "undefined")
    socket.sockets.in(client.room).emit("isTyping", {isTyping: data, person: people[client.id].name});
    client.broadcast.to(client.room).emit("isTyping", {isTyping: data, person: people[client.id].name});
console.log("Someone is typing");
});
```

Comment: I would keep a defined duration, if user is not typing(`keyup`) for that much time, invoke `"notTyping"`

Comment: That works already. I need the function to stop when the user hit enter (sends the message)

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8ps2wcur/1/

Comment: You're not handing the case when the user hits the Enter key.

Comment: That still doesn't take 'hitting enter' into account. Please check out my posted code in my question. I have no problems with removing 'is typing' after a duration of time

Comment: @JonasSH where is the code to handle hitting Enter? You have `if (e.which !== 13)` but no `else`. Nothing is triggered when the user hits Enter.

Comment: I updated my question with extra code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are simply just missing the case when the user hits the Enter key. You need to add to your `if` statement.

```
$("#msg").keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.which !== 13) {
        typing = true; // we know the user is typing because they have pressed a key but not 'Enter'
        socket.emit("typing", true);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(timeoutFunction, 1500);
    } else {
        clearTimeout(timeout); // no need to fire the timeoutFunction twice (as we do it on the next line)
        timeoutFunction(); // probably needs a better name but this will immediately send the necessary `socket.emit('typing', false)` when the enter key is pressed
    }
});
```

Comment: `clearTimeout(timeout);` is present in both the conditions, why to repeat it ?

Comment: @Rayon I've added some comments that hopefully helps explain it a little better. You could also bring this completely outside of the `if` statement with something like: `if (timeout) { clearTimeout(timeout) }`. This could go above the `if` block and it would work the same.

Comment: Check out the updated code in my question. The code for Enter does not work

Comment: @JonasSH you're still not sending the event to the server. And does the keypress function have `data` in its scope? I'm becoming confused at how this code is/should be working. Is the problem that the user typing stills sees that they are typing, that other people in the room sees the message that the user is still typing, or both?

Comment: Sorry sockets and node.js is completely new to me. I need it to work like this: 1. the $("#msg").keypress(function(e) {} sends the event to the server ("typing"). 2. the server "typing" sends the event to "isTyping" on the client-side.. All of this works perfectly fine. But I have no idea of how and where to add code, that would take 'hitting' Enter into account

Comment: Did you try the answer I gave? Does anything happen? Try putting a breakpoint on that `if` block and follow the execution.

Comment: Just tried out your answer. It removes the 'is typing' but adds it again on the next keystroke. Hitting Enter doesn't do anything

Comment: Sorry @adam-beck your answer works! I didn't add it right at first. Thanks